# mysql_real_escape_string escaping single quote into MYSQL entry

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I enter this into my form field: `O'mally`

I run this code on the text:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $form[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value); //Escape input.
}
```

The POST output is: `O'mally`

The output of the `$form` variable after running the code listed above is: `O\'mally`

The query is:

```
mysql_query("insert into tbl_test 
                (lastName) 
                values 
                ('{$form['lastName']}')")
```

The database gets `O\'mally` inserted into it (I want `O'mally` to be inserted, not WITH the escape).

What am I doing wrong here?

I have confirmed that **magic quotes is OFF** via `phpinfo()`.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you execute the mySQL statement?

Comment: Use prepared statements instead, then you don't have to escape at all.

Comment: @AlexLunix on all new code, I do use PDO.  Unfortunately I'm supporting a legacy application here...

Comment: What is the value of `$value` before escaping it? And I completely concur with @AlexLunix; use prepared statements, they safe you from a lot of trouble.

Comment: @knittl $value is the direct input value from the post: `O'mally`

Comment: @Michael as indicated in original post - this is OFF.

Comment: Can you try to echo the query itself instead of executing? You must be getting a backslash from somewhere – maybe you escape it twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to output O'mally from database to browser, just use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function.

Comment: I thought that using mysql_real_escape_string meant it went into the DB without escape characters, so you would NOT need to use stripslashes?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string escapes them directly.